# unable to train on complete batch in tensorflow in google collab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I was trying to train a convolutional neural network to classify cats vs dogs in google collab
here is the code I am using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import time

Name = 'Cat-vs-Dogs-cnn-64x3-sigmoid-w-o-dense-v3' + str((int(time.time())))
di =  "C:\\Users\\naval\\neural_network\\cats_dogs\\logs" + Name

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=di)

DML_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1,0"
x = pickle.load(open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/data/x.pickle",'rb'))
y = pickle.load(open("//content//drive//MyDrive//Colab Notebooks//data//y.pickle",'rb'))
print(x.shape)
x = x.reshape(-1,80,80,1)
x = x/255.0

modle = Sequential()
modle.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape = x.shape[1:]))
modle.add(layers.Activation ('relu'))
modle.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

modle.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),input_shape = x.shape[1:]))
modle.add(layers.Activation ('relu'))
modle.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

modle.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
modle.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
modle.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

modle.add(layers.Flatten())

modle.add(layers.Dense(1))
modle.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

modle.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),
             loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

modle.fit(x,y,batch_size=32,epochs = 9,validation_split=0.3,callbacks = [tensorboard])
```

the code works fine while using it on my own machine
here is the screenshot of its training on my local device:[image]

the dimensions of x and y are as follows:

```
tf.shape(x) = tf.Tensor([24946    80    80     1], shape=(4,), dtype=int32) 
tf.shape(y) = tf.Tensor([24946], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

obviously my gpu isn't powerful enough so I shifted my code to google collab
and here is snapshot of its training in collab with gpu acceleration enabled:
[image]

the problem is that on my local computer neural network is training on complete data set while on collab it is only training on (complete dataset / batch_size).
Any fixes for this problem?? also training on my collab is very slow as compared to other people using it

Also I am using tensorflow-directml on AMD readon-RX-5500M is this is useful..

Comment: before model.fit, add print(tf.shape(x)) and print(tf.shape(y)) and post the result.

Comment: the output of 
tf.shape(x) = tf.Tensor([24946    80    80     1], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
and
 tf.shape(y) = tf.Tensor([24946], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)

Comment: Do you use GPU on your Colab Runtime? You can change it using Runtime>change_runtime_type. Also using a smaller batch_size, will affecting on your speed, and using whole data is much different than using batch_size 32

Comment: Do you get any error on Colab or the problem is just speed?

Comment: problem is that on my local machine model is training on the complete batch(i.e. on 24946 data sets) but on collab it is training on only 24946/32(ie total feature size/batch size)

Comment: also, I am using GPU acceleration.